# Firefox Filter Animations

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I've got a div with an animation on working perfectly in Chrome.

Here is the code...

```
@-webkit-keyframes adjustHue {
    0% { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg); }
    25% { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(45deg); }
    50% { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg); }
    75% { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(135deg); }
    100% { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg); }
}

.blocky {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

-webkit-animation: adjustHue 4s alternate infinite;
-moz-animation: adjustHue 4s alternate infinite;
-o-animation: adjustHue 4s alternate infinite;
animation: adjustHue 4s alternate infinite;
}
```

So I can copy the -webkit-keyframes adjustHue, and replicate for -moz-keyframes adjustHue, and even just keyframes adjustHue, but I've tried swapping -webkit-filter for -moz-filter or even just filter with no success. Basically I need the effect that I am using to work cross browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility), `filter` is not yet supported in Firefox. You could try achieving this another way, but for now, filter won't work in Firefox yet.

Comment: Ah right, I've had a search on Google for an alternative but can't quite find anything.

Comment: You could try doing the whole thing within a <svg> tag and then apply [SVG filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter) to it directly instead of via CSS, but I don't think that would really be practical in most cases. It might be useful for some situations though.

Comment: Would there be any way of replicating it in jQuery as a backup?

Comment: I tried googling it, but couldn't find anything about it. I think this is not possible, but you could try creating another question asking that, to see if anyone else knows a way.