# Replicate CSS filter using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an issue where I'm trying to replicate some filter functionality found in CSS, but at the moment it is only working in WebKit browsers, due to Firefox's lack of filter support.
More information about specifics can be found here > [Firefox Filter Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937960/firefox-filter-animations)

Specifically, I am trying to replicate -web-kit-filter: hue-rotate(x) in jQuery,
you can see the webkit animation here: http://omega.themestrapped.com

I've tried searching Google to no avail, and wondered if there was any jQuery gurus which could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, it [is not supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#hue-rotate%28%29), it may be worth looking at either [PaintbrushJS](http://mezzoblue.github.io/PaintbrushJS/demo/index.html) (see the color tint demo), [pusher.color](http://tech.pusherhq.com/libraries/color) or [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/hsl/)