# Replicate filter (hue-rotate) in Firefox? (dynamically)

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have an image which has this 'hue' class:

```
.hue {
        -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out; 
     transition:all 1s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg); 
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg); 
}
```

Then I change this hue with jquery:

```
$('.hue').css({
        '-webkit-filter'    : 'hue-rotate('+d+'deg)', 
        'filter'            : 'hue-rotate('+d+'deg)'  

});
```

which happens slowly as it should in Chrome and Safari (webkit). What do I need to do to get this working in Firefox?

As far as I know there is no -moz-filter or -moz-transition ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)) and hue-rotate should work in FF ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#hue-rotate%28%29)).

There is almost the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951009/replicate-css-filter-using-jquery) but the answer doesn't suit me since libraries like [PaintbrushJS](http://mezzoblue.github.io/PaintbrushJS/demo/index.html) have predefined filters whereas I need to set hue value myself.

Any help or workaround to accomplish this in FF highly appreciated!

**EDIT:** [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/hsl/) seems to allow setting custom values, but I can't apply the transition or slow effect ... This is the last issue now :)

**EDIT2** I managed to set hue on FF with the help of SVG (rather ugly). If you add next line to your css (next to -webkit-filter which works for Chrome and Safari):

```
filter:url(file.svg#myFilter)
```

and create file.svg :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
   <filter id="myFilter">
     <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="140"/>
   </filter>
   <filter id="myFilter2">
     <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="50"/>
   </filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

this works. Anyhow it fails when trying to change it dynamically like this:

```
$('.hue').css({
    '-webkit-filter'    : 'hue-rotate('+d+'deg)', /* this works */
    'filter'            : 'url(filters.svg#'+myFilterName+')' /* this doesnt */
});
```

(I can see that the change on the element occurred but page just goes white)

Answer (score 0):

This is experimental technology that doesn't have support in FF as to now. Have a look at the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility), from the same page of the link you provided.

I suggest opening a suggestion for implementation with [PaintbrushJS](http://github.com/mezzoblue/PaintbrushJS) or Pixstatic with the improvements you mentioned (Pixstatic doesn't seem to be open source so you'll have to maybe contact them through email).

Maybe even implement a new filter into PaintbrushJS yourself and issue a pull request!

Comment: Actually, when looking through the FF support, I saw it has support for `link(url to svg filter)`. [Explained here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/filter-primitives/), although I reckon your best course of action would be svg filters on svg photo (also explained in the same page).

Comment: Before I came back to check for answers I ran into filter:url(file.svg#filter) and it seems to do the job in FF. But unfortunately changing it with jquery doesn't work.